# Packaging for Android failed due to "source release 1.8 requires target release 1.8"

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx

I'm trying to perform packaging for Android based on [this Gradle on Commandline](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline#packaging-the-project) wiki article, however I'm not successful due to error:

> [ERROR] [system.err] javacTask: source release 1.8 requires target release 1.8

I was trying to run the gradle command with `--debug` param like this:

```
gradlew android:assembleDebug --debug
```

and in logs I can see such lines:

> 01:51:53.707 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.RebuildIncrementalTaskInputs] All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> 01:51:53.707 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Task] Compiling with source level 1.8 and target level 1.7.
>
> ...
>
> 01:51:53.731 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler] Compiler arguments: -source 1.8 -target 1.7 -d ...

How the heck is he getting this **1.7**? I tried to change source/target versions in `core/build.gradle` and `android/build.gradle` to 1.7 (and ofc fix all issues after this change) but unfortunately with no effect

Did anyone meet this issue? How to handle this?

---

I'm using JDK jdk1.8.0_73

I have SDK path defined inside `local.properties` file however I have also the `ANDROID_HOME` system variable (Windows here) set - to the same SDK location

I'm using the default `build.gradle` files so for the `core/build.gradle` I have

```
apply plugin: "java"

targetCompatibility = 1.8
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]


eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}
```

and for the `android/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.1"
    compileSdkVersion 28
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/robovm/ios/robovm.xml'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mantkowicz.light.game"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() {
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if (outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}
task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.mantkowicz.light.game/com.mantkowicz.light.game.AndroidLauncher'
}
// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [project.configurations.compile]
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}
// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [COMPILE: [plus: [project.configurations.compile]]]

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value: "true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
}
```

Comment: In `android { compileOptions { ...}}` try adding `targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`. Just a guess.

Comment: yes it worked - thank you very much :) would you like to create answer so I could accept it?